# Why is my onclick button is calling a function when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm working in NodeJS with Express. I'm having a problem with my EJS client side file right now for a button click.

I have a function from a JS file imported to my EJS file, and I can call it by doing `<% helper.test() %>`

However, my button decides to call this function whenever the page loads instead of doing it when I click the button.

```
<button onclick="<% helper.test() %>">Button Test</button>
```

If I change the button code to be

```
<button onclick="helper.test()">Button Test</button>
```

it says that helper isn't defined. I'm new to all this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think its supposed to be <button onclick="<% helper.test %>"

Comment: otherwise the functions is callled automatically instead of onClick

Comment: Is `helper.test` a method defined on the front-end or the back-end?

Comment: @TalmacelMarianSilviu It doesn't run on load anymore, but it also doesn't run when I click the button

Comment: @HenryWoody it is defined on backend and imported to the client side ejs file

Comment: I don't believe you can call back-end methods directly from the front-end. You'd need to either define the function in JS for the front-end so it can be called or expose an HTTP endpoint on the server that calls the method and the button can make a request to that endpoint. The server and the client are separate applications that can only communicate with each other via HTTP.

Comment: @HenryWoody I can get it working if it's not in the onclick, but thats the problem

Comment: Can you try like this? <%= helper.test() %> or <%= helper.test %>

Comment: @TalmacelMarianSilviu it runs on page load with that

Comment: did you add the = sign?

Comment: @TalmacelMarianSilviu yeah lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `helper.test` is a method defined on the server, the client is not able to call this method directly. The client and the server are separate applications that can only communicate with each other using HTTP.

You can instead define an HTTP endpoint on your server that invokes `helper.test` and have your button make a request to that endpoint.

Here's a rough example:

Server:

```js
router.get("/helper_test", () => {
    helper.test();
});
```

Client:

```html
<button onclick="callHelperTest()">">Button Test</button>

<script>
function callHelperTest() {
    fetch("/helper_test");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. I'll try in the next couple days

Comment: Something very similar to this worked! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

it is probably for the parenthesis on the attribute "onclick".
Try the code of your button this manner:

```
<button onclick="<% helper.test %>">Button Test</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't run on load anymore, but it also doesn't run when I click the button

Comment: I believe that the @henry-woody reply correctly, i am still novice with this framework.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, remove () from helper.test()

```
<button onclick="helper.test">Button Test</button>
```

Comment: It says helper isn't defined if I try this, if I add <% %> to it, nothing happens